# Implementing for loops in R

Tags: r

I currently have stored my values in a vector

```
myVector
[1] 0.5 0.6 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.0
```

I want to loop through this vector and for each j multiply the rest of the members (as long as they are not 0) * (1-myVector[j])

So for example if j was at the second position, I would want to do:

```
0.5 * (1-0.6) * (0.1) * (0.2)
```

My first time working with R so any tips will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
for(j in seq_along(v[v>0])){
   print((1-v[v>0][j]) * Reduce(`*`,v[v>0][-j]))
}
[1] 0.006
[1] 0.004
[1] 0.054
[1] 0.024
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `for` loop as :

```
myVector <- c(0.5, 0.6, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.0) 
result <- numeric(length(myVector))

for(i in seq_along(myVector)) {
  result[i] <- (1 - myVector[i]) * prod(replace(myVector[-i], myVector[-i] == 0, 1))
}
result
#[1] 0.006 0.004 0.006 0.054 0.024 0.006
```

---

If you don't want to output for 0 values :

```
myVector <- c(0.5, 0.6, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.0) 
myNewVec <- myVector[myVector != 0]
result <- numeric(length(myNewVec))

for(i in seq_along(myNewVec)) {
  result[i] <- (1 - myNewVec[i]) * prod(myNewVec[-i])
}
result
#[1] 0.006 0.004 0.054 0.024
```

Comment: hi, I get an unexpected ',' error for comma in this line (== 0, 1))

Comment: Are you sure you are copying the code in my post as it is? It works for me without any error with the data in my post. I remove additional space in the answer see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with the apply family of functions to loop over each value and `prod` to get the product of each value.

```
vec <- c(0.5, 0.6, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.0) 

sapply(vec, function(x) prod( vec[!(vec %in% c(0, x))], (1-x) ) )
#[1] 0.006 0.004 0.006 0.054 0.024 0.006
```

**Edit:** If you want to iterate over the index you can do the following.

```
sapply(seq_along(vec), function (i) prod( vec[-c(which(vec == 0), i)], 1 - vec[i]))
```

Comment: Won't work if there are duplicated values in vec.  You'll need to remove by index rather than matching.

Comment: Hi, i dont need to consider the cases where vec[j] is 0. So there should be only 4 values outputted

Comment: @27ϕ9 you're right, doesnt work with duplicate ones

Answer (score 0):

The short solution:

```
output = NULL
for (j in 1:length(myVector)){ 
    output[j] = Reduce('*',c((1-myVector[j]),setdiff(myVector[-j],0)))
}
```

The explanation:

- Reduce('*', c(...)) -> multiply every element in the collection c(...)
- setdiff(some_vector, 0) -> excludes value 0 from the given vector
- myVector(-j) -> returns all elements of the vector except the jth element

So for the below vector, the output is:

```
myVector = myVector = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.0) # input
> output
[1] 0.006 0.004 0.006 0.054 0.024 0.006
```